# android 2.2 and serial communication

Tags: android

I have an android tablet running 2.2. I need to implement serial communication with another device. I was wondering if anyone had any experience implementing that? Is there a library that someone used? or would that be helpful to root the device?
From searching the internet found some api but it was device specific.. 
The following api that i found is only for HTC devices http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/w/list

Answer (score 0):

I've used that serialport-api project and it also worked on some Arnova 7&8 tablets. So you can try to use it, but you will need to root the device in order to be able to write/read to the serial ports. If you need some info let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I think we decided not to root the device. Our alternative is to use bluetooth to transfer data.

Comment: @Ovidiu Lactu, I'm interested on your answer... Can you tell me your code please?